# Serialize custom generic collection using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

Let's say there is the following generic collection:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> _items;

    public bool MySpecialProperty { get; set; }

    public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _items = collection;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to serialize this collection using by `DataContractSerializer`:

```
MyCollection<int> original = new MyCollection<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }) 
{ 
    MySpecialProperty = false 
};
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyCollection<int>));
var builder = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(builder))
{
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, original);
}
var serialized = builder.ToString();
```

I know, it is possible by using [`DataContractAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for the collection definition and [`DataMemberAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for `_items` and `MySpecialProperty` members. But is there a way to serialize my class as ordinary collection? So, I expect the following XML:

```
<MyCollection>  
    <Item>1</Item>  
    <Item>2</Item>  
    <Item>3</Item>
    <MySpecialProperty>false</MySpecialProperty>  
</MyCollection>
```

I have tried to use [`CollectionDataContractAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for the collection definition and [`DataMemberAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for `MySpecialProperty`, but it causes `System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException` exception in *System.Runtime.Serialization.dll*. Is there another way to get the above-mentioned XML result?

Comment: There is no way to do this other than implementing [`IXmlSerializable`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly).  Need more details?

Comment: @dbc, I like your idea. But I think  the `IXmlSerializable` is intended for `XmlSerializer`. I'm not sure a `DataContractSerializer` uses `IXmlSerializable` members of serializing instance too. Am I wrong?

Comment: `IXmlSerializable` is supported, see [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer): *Additionally, types that implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface are supported, ...*

Comment: It's awesome! @dbc, thank you very much!